# Webpack warning when building d3-tip

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've included `d3-tip` in my `d3` implementation by using the following code:

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
import * as d3Tip from "d3-tip";
d3.tip = d3Tip;
```

However, I'm getting the following warning:

```
WARNING in ./~/babel-loader/lib!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/opsboard/opsboard.vue
75:16-22 "export 'tip' (imported as 'd3') was not found in 'd3'
```

Anyone got any ideas what's wrong?  The tip is working correctly.  Because I'm assigning `d3.tip` to be `d3Tip` I don't get why it's exporting it...

Comment: any luck on this issue?

Comment: @Jared afraid not 

Answer (score 0):

This code shouldn't cause warnings:

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
import d3Tip from "d3-tip";
...
const tip = d3Tip();
svg.call(tip);
```

Hope it helps